# How can LIMIT 1 possibly make a query slower

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance, mysql-5.6

Given this table in MySQL 5.6:

```
create table PlayerSession
(
    id bigint auto_increment primary key,
    lastActivity datetime not null,
    player_id bigint null,
    ...
    constraint FK4410E05525A98981
        foreign key (player_id) references Player (id)
)
```

How can it possibly be that this query returns about 2000 rows instantly:

```
SELECT * FROM PlayerSession
WHERE player_id = ....
ORDER BY lastActivity DESC
```

but adding `LIMIT 1` makes it take 4 seconds, even though all that should do is pick the first result?

Using `EXPLAIN` I found the only difference to be that without the limit, `filesort` is used. From what I gather, this should make it slower, not faster. The whole table contains about 2M rows.
Also, adding `LIMIT 3` or anything higher than that, gives the same performance as no limit.

And yes, I have since created an index on `playerId, lastActivity`, which, surprise surprise, makes it fast again. While that takes the immediate stress out of the situation (the server was rather overloaded), it doesn't really explain the mystery.

Comment: You should use the Query Planner to observe perfomance between both of these query. I think you are using a bad index that cause a re-calucation with the LIMIT clause.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. When using `LIMIT 1` and you have no index, the database chooses the wrong execution plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What specific version of 5.6?  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; we need to see the other indexes, plus datatypes.

`INDEX(playerId, lastActivity)` lets the query avoid "filesort".

A possible reason for the strange timings could be caching.  Run each query twice to avoid that hiccup.

Comment: I see I never got around to investigating this further. The problem hasn't come up anymore though, and we're on 8.0 now. In any case, here's a check mark for your efforts.